# Git gui here and bash not showing on other folders in windows

Tags: git, bash

I already re-installed git on my windows to select git gui and git bash here option on context menu. It's already working when i right click on desktop and local c folder, but not appearing on my git branch folders. Why is it like that? does it should be working on my branch folder so i can open the gui window directly on that folder? BTW, im using the latest version of git for windows.

Thanks for the comment in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "Branch folder"? Could you post your "branch folder" path, and the contents inside the folder?